# Why does my app show a box with question mark on mmssheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an app that makes use of iMessage and MMS.

```
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    if (imageDataSampleBuffer) {
```

The problem is, after I take a picture then click the send button, the image randomly becomes a question mark.

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
```

The above code was the first the one we used followed by:

```
[self sendSMSmessage:myMessage image:imageData];
```

next, in the sendSMSmessage method, the following codes were called:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *myText = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
[myText setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
[myText setBody:myMessage];
[myText addAttachmentData:image typeIdentifier:@"image/jpeg" filename:@"image.jpeg"];
```

Then, I present the  MFMessageComposeViewController myText

```
[self presentViewController:myText animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, I clicked Send... It successfully sent for the app and I can see the picture on MFMessageComposeViewController. But when I try to look at iMessage, some of the pictures I tried to send is good. But some are not. Some show question mark. Did the images got corrupted in the process or what? I tried to compress the image using the following:

```
CGFloat compressionQuality = 0.3;
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:(UIImageJPEGRepresentation
                                                  ([UIImage imageWithData:[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer]]
                                                   , compressionQuality))];
```

but still performs the same. In 10 tries, I get something like 4 failed images. Could it be a problem in iPhone or just my app itself? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if some people would experience this, but the thing I did to fix this was:

Declaring the imageData as a strong reference:

```
__strong NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
```

And then I changed the typeIdentifier of the myText composer into @"public.jpeg" instead of @"image/jpeg"

```
[myText addAttachmentData:image typeIdentifier:@"public.jpeg" filename:@"image.jpeg"];
```